# "A math class", "math classes" or "math class" in context

Tags: articles

Tell me please which sentence sounds the most natural.

> What are you doing after **a math class**?
>
> What are you doing after **math classes**.
>
> What are you doing after **math class**.

What I am trying to ask is what the person is doing after they are done with their lesson in math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

> What are you doing after math classes?

You want to know generally what someone is planning to do as a routine after each and every math class.

Or:

> What are you doing after math class?

You want to know what someone is doing after a single math class. You're also assuming they know which one you're talking about - it would usually be assumed to mean the next one, or more specifically, perhaps, today's, ans if it weren't today's, you may hear something more specific like:

> What are you doing after Tuesday's math class?

Or:

> What are you doing after math [class] on Tuesday?

In this second example, the "class" is optional, and would most likely not be said.